# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Hangman1 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random ran = new Random();
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("word.txt"));   
    String dictionary = file.nextLine();

    char array2[];
    array2 = new char[7];

    String wordlist[] =    {"accoutrements","acumen","anomalistic","auspicious","bellwether","callipygian","circumlocution"};
    int number = ran.nextInt(3);
    String in = null;
    in = wordlist[number];
    //System.out.println(number);
    String guess;
    int numofchances = 8,k=0;

    boolean array[],b=true;
    array = new boolean[in.length()];
    for (int u=0;u<in.length();u++)
    {
        array[u]=false;
    }

    while(numofchances >= 1 && b){
        numofchances--;
        System.out.println("Enter your guess: ");
        guess = input.nextLine();
        char character = guess.charAt(0);
        array2[k] = character;
        k++;
        for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++){
            char c = in.charAt(i);
            if(c == character || array[i]==true){
                System.out.print(c+" ");
                array[i] = true;
            }else{
                System.out.print("_ ");

            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            System.out.print(array2[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        b = false;
        System.out.println();
        for (int i=0;i<in.length();i++){
            if (array[i]==false)
                b=true;
        }
    }



}
}
```

How do you fix this error? Whenever I enter more than 7 letters, this error occurs at the line "array2[k] = character;"

Output:
Enter your guess: 
a
a _ _ _ _ _ 
a

Enter your guess: 
b
a _ _ _ _ _ 
ab

Enter your guess: 
f
a _ _ _ _ _ 
abf

Enter your guess: 
d
a _ _ _ _ _ 
abfd

Enter your guess: 
f
a _ _ _ _ _ 
abfdf

Enter your guess: 
r
a _ _ _ _ _ 
abfdfr

Enter your guess: 
f
a _ _ _ _ _ 
abfdfrf

Enter your guess: 
f
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at Hangman1.main(Hangman1.java:35)

Answer (score 2):

```
array2[k] = character;
       ^------ k == 7 on the last iteration, but array2 is only of size 7.
```

Change the size of array2 to 8:

```
array2 = new char[8];
```

Better yet, use a constant for this size, and use that constant everywhere needed.

Comment: Since the loop is filled by iterating numofchances times, then the OP should create array2 with a length of numofchances.  It is best to use the same variable so as one changes, both change.  Or, better yet, as you suggested, make it a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Either increase the size of the array i.e. `array2` to more than 7 or use auto growing `List`.

```
   List<String> list= new LinkedList<String>();

   list.add(String.valueOf(c));
```

where `c` is the `char`.